# sort on a class member got the error unresolved overloaded function type

Tags: c++, sorting

```
class S {
    public:
        vector <int> ia;
        int rank;
        bool cmp(S const &s1, S const &s2) {
            return (s1.rank > s2.rank);
        }
        void sort_on_rank() {
            sort(ia.begin(), ia.end(), cmp);
        }
};
```

This piece of code is trying to sort the vector on rank, but doesn't compile because of following error,
[Error] no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator, )'

Please help me on this and tell where is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your program it seems you want to sort objects of `S` classes. In that case your vector should be like this : `std::vector<S>`.

Your `cmp` is a non-static member function of class `S` and hence `std::sort` cannot work with it. (Think about how will you use the function).

You can either overload `<` operator for your class or pass a stand-alone/static member function or you can use C++11 lambda expression.

Thus your class becomes:

```
class S {
    public:
        vector<S> ia;
        int rank;
        void sort_on_rank() {
            sort(ia.begin(), ia.end(), 
                 [] (S const &s1, S const &s2) {
                     return (s1.rank > s2.rank);
                 });
        }
};
```

However if you want to merely sort vector containing `int` in descending order, just call `std::sort` with a C++11 lambda that returns `lhs > rhs`.

```
std::sort(ia.begin(), ia.end(), [](int x, int y) { return x > y; });
```

Comment: Yes, I want to sort objects of S class. What will it look like if using lambda expression?

Comment: Answer edited. See how a comparison function as lambda is passed to `sort` routine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `S::cmp()` takes `S`, but `S::ia`'s value type is `int`.